# How to run PHP from command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, cron

I am trying to create a cron job that will back up my MySQL database. However it doesn't seem to ever call it.

I then tried to check if I could even run it from the terminal and I can't do that either. What is the problem?

I don't understand what the PATH variable means, I guess it must be something to do with that?

I'm just running `php /var/www/html/backup.php`

Comment: What output do you see when you run `php /var/www/html/backup.php`?

Comment: Is php installed on the machine?  Try `which php` or `whereis php` to see if the executable is present.

Comment: I assume we are talking Unix here right?

Comment: it doesn't output anything, `which php` prints `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: Yeah, Debian on a raspberry pi

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I'm assuming that or OSX or BSD since the mention of `cron`.  Hope we don't find out it's being run Cygwin or something :)

Comment: If which php doesn't work then it's installed somethere not in your search path.  Do you know where it's installed?  How did you install it (apt-get?)

Answer (score 1):

If php installed , go to the specified file location (cd to the file location in terminal) and enter below

```
php exampleFile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `php` if it's not there.

Try `apt-get install php` for debian http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php

I've you've got it installed, try to use the full path to executable:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/backup.php
```

(Replacing /user/local/bin with the actual path to the php executable)

Comment: I've got php installed

Comment: @user2397282 where is php installed?

Comment: I'm guessing it's `/usr/bin/php` as that's the result i get from running `which php`?

Comment: and `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/backup.php` doesn't work?

Comment: @user2397282 when yourun  `/usr/bin/php --version` what do you see? do you get something like `No such file or directory`

Comment: It works! But it seems as though it only works in the directory containing `backup.php`? Which isn't too great, because my cron jobs will not be running in that directory

Comment: once again, try adding the explicit path to the file, it should run from anywhere.  `/usr/bin/php backup.php` will obviously only run from the directory `backup.php` is in but  `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/backup.php` should run anywhere.  IF the script writes somehting to local disk, it needs to do it somewhere the user writing has permissions and in a directory with write enabled for that user

Comment: I can run `/usr/bin/php backup.php` and `php backup.php` from inside the `backup.php` directory. However, I cannot run `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/backup.php` from outside that directory.

Comment: Is the php error you see `Could not open input file: backup.php` when you try to run it outside the `/var/www/html/` directory?

Comment: Then it's running.  Maybe not doing what you want, but running and not throwing an error.  You need to start debugging the script to find out the issue.

Comment: But how come it works if you run it in the right directory? Surely by specifying the full path it should run just fine?

Comment: Add to your post what the expected "works fine" is (is it expected to write a file, read some file, hit a service, etc...)  and post the relevant code from you php script that 'should be working' in your question